# How to get the URL of a type 'submit' button during Cypress test?

Tags: cypress, submit-button

Below is a submit button on the page I am trying to test.

When you click this button, a pop-up window is displayed. The URL of this pop-up is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/........etc`.

[image]

This sign in uses SSO, but we are having difficulty bypassing the sign-in process using requests.

So we are instead trying to capture the URL of the pop-up during the test.

I have seen examples where people retrieve the `href` attribute of a button. However, as you can see above, there is no `href` on this button.

I've searched the HTML for a `form` element too, but can't find that.

I'm just wondering, is there a way I can get the URL of the pop-up window that clicking the above button generates?

Comment: We have tried to bypass the SSO using `cy.request()`, but the problem is that our authentication uses Azure Active Directory, then goes to Okta, & then goes back to AAD, so it's quite complex

Answer (score 0):

To catch the URL, try adding an intercept before the click

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '*').as('submit')

cy.get('button').click()

cy.wait('@submit').then(interception => {
  console.log(interception.request.url)
})
```

**Note** this is debugging code only to help find the URL. Don't use it in a long-term test.

**Additional notes:**

- I'm assuming `'POST'` as it's most common for `submit`, but may need `'GET'` instead.
- using `'*'` will catch *anything*, so you may catch so stray requests from the page load with the first `cy.wait('@submit')`. If so, just add more `cy.wait('@submit')` or a long `cy.wait()` before the click.

Answer (score 0):

The new tab is likely to be trigger via javascript. If it is using [`window.open`][1] the you can stub it to open in the same ta

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').callsFake((url, target) => {
      expect(target).to.be.undefined
      // call the original `win.open` method
      // but pass the `_self` argument
      return win.open.wrappedMethod.call(win, url, '_self')
    }).as('open')
  })
  cy.get('a').click()
  cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledOnceWithExactly', 'url')
})


  [1]: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowopen
```